# Infinitive usage pattern

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, infinitive-clauses

What is the difference in meaning of the below two sentences? Are both of them correct? If so, what is the difference in meaning of these two sentences

1)She was heard to sing a song by them.

2)She was heard by them to sing a song.

Answer (score 1):

(2) means 'They heard her sing a song'.

Because *by them* is separated from *heard*, (1) could be understood to mean 'Someone heard her sing a song by them', where 'they' are two song-writers.